# the time change when send a time from angular to .net web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am sending the bellow object  from agular js (from pickertime) to the web api

```
Id : "14607"
PartyId : "31558"
Time : Thu Jan 01 1970 08:30:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

but on my web api in Time It received... (the time is different)

```
Id : 14607
PartyId : 31558
Time : {1/1/1970 4:30:00 PM}
```

How can I fix this to get the same time?

```
public class PersonalVM
    {

        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int? PartyId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Time { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I changed DateTime by DateTimeOffset and I got the same result.

Comment: That happens because when `Date` object passes via payload, it perform serialization before sending that object to server.. In serialization process it tries to convert date into locale date by adding/substracting GMT component from date object.. In this case if your date has -8GMT it will add that time to date when it arrives to server, to solve this issue you should store date into UTC time

Comment: Thanks. You gave me the idea The solutions was Model.Time.HasValue ? TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Model.Time.Value).ToShortTimeString()

Comment: I have been doing something like this...
if( candidate.DateOfBirth.HasValue)
                candidate.DateOfBirth = candidate.DateOfBirth.Value.ToLocalTime();
But its a bit of a faff.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions was `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Model.Time.Value).ToShortTimeString()`

Comment: This solution will not work when the API and UI hosted in different server.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) instead of a string

Assuming u are working on asp.net core webapi.
I m using a converter for json it converts unix timestamp to or from  dateTime or Datetimeoffset

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;

namespace JsonConverters
{
    public class UnixDateTimeMilisecondsConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
    {
        internal static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

       
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            long milliseconds;

            if (value is null)
            {
                milliseconds = 0;
            }
            else if (value is DateTime dateTime)
            {
                milliseconds = (long)(dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
            }
            else if (value is DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset)
            {
                milliseconds = dateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Expected date object value.");
            }

            if (milliseconds < 0)
            {
                //  long? t = null;
                //  writer.WriteValue(t);
                //   return;
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Cannot convert date value that is before Unix epoch of 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.");
            }

            writer.WriteValue(milliseconds);
        }

        
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            bool nullable = IsNullable(objectType);
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            {
                if (!nullable)
                {
                    throw new JsonSerializationException($"Cannot convert null value to {objectType}.");
                }

                return null;
            }

            long miliSeconds;

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
            {
                miliSeconds = (long)reader.Value;
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            {
                if (!long.TryParse((string)reader.Value, out miliSeconds))
                {
                    throw new JsonSerializationException($"Cannot convert invalid value to {objectType}.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unexpected token parsing date. Expected Integer or String, got  {reader.TokenType}.");
            }

            if (miliSeconds >= 0)
            {
                DateTime d = UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(miliSeconds);

                Type t = (nullable)
                    ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType)
                    : objectType;
                if (t == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
                {
                    return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(miliSeconds);
                }
                return d;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Cannot convert value that is before Unix epoch of 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 to {0}.  {objectType}.");
            }
        }

        private static bool IsNullable(Type type)
        {
            return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
        }
    }
}
```

to configure it in ur startup.configure

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = options.SerializerSettings;
                serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UnixDateTimeMilisecondsConverter());
            });
```

Now on angular side u have to send or receive just unix timestamp.
how ?

Use Momnetjs for clinet side and make ur life easier.